# Jira automatically assign based on column

Tags: kanban, jira

I have a Kanban board in Jira with several columns:

1. Selected For Development -> unassigned
2. In Progress -> assigned to developer1
3. Ready For Testing -> assigned to tester1
4. In Testing -> assigned to tester1
5. Done -> unassigned

How can I make the assignation of tasks automatic based on the column they are in?

Answer (score 2):

You can link an assignment to a [workflow transition](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/advanced-workflow-configuration-938847443.html#Advancedworkflowconfiguration-postfunctions).

For example, when a ticket is moved from Selected For Development to In Progress it follows a workflow transition. If you go in and modify your workflow you can associate that transition with a post function that updates the ticket assignee.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an automation rule that watches for the specific transition you are looking for, like awaiting approval to in progress, and assign the issue to a group.

This article talks about the automatic assignment [Auto-assign issues in Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/automation-template-library/auto-assign)

This rule detects the transition of the workflow. [image]

This is a good way to set the actions you want to take place on a specific transition, you can use the "If" statements to narrow down the issues you want these rules to take place on, even updating other fields or choosing different groups based on criteria.